# Android to have swipe able tabs at the bottom with icons in it

Tags: android, tabs, swipe-gesture, pagerslidingtabstrip

Hi I'm trying to a create an app with swipe able tabs with icons in it and the tab bar should be placed at the bottom of the page. Can anyone show any tutorial for getting this..?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this link in github

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/

or this example http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/android-tabhost-at-bottom-of-the-screen.html

```
  package com.viralandroid.androidtabsatbottom;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.TabHost;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TabHost tabHost;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
    host.addTab(spec);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     
  present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
 }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabHost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></TabWidget>

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffc916"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="This is tab 1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#da8200"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="This is tab 2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#5b89ff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="This is tab 3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
 </TabHost>
```